# How do I change the font size of the labels in a Django form?

Tags: css, django, forms, django-forms

I tried changing the font size and also the styling using `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):`. But it is changing the contents' size and styling within the input field.

Please help me change the size, styling and other attributes of the form labels. Fields such as `username`,  `password` come from the form labels defined in `forms.py`. And I want to define the font size/type of these fields, I'm not sure how this could be done.

[image]

Here is the code snippet where I tried this :

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
username = UsernameField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': True, 'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'font-size: 30px;'}))
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'current-password', 'class': 'form-control'}))

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['username'].label = 'Username:'
    self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({'style': 'font-size: 78px;'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Django generates labels automatically based on the field names unless you explicitly specify those.

Please modify your code referring to this snippet, hope it helps

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
username = UsernameField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': True, 'class': 'form-control'}))
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'current-password', 'class': 'form-control'}))

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({'style': 'font-size: 30px;'})
    self.fields['username'].label = 'Custom Username Label:'
    self.fields['password'].label = 'Custom Password Label:'
```

Remember to customize the attributes and styling based on your requirements and preferences.

Feel free to ask if anything else is needed.

............................................................
............................................................

Edit
Try this specifically for labels..

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = UsernameField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': True, 'class': 'form-control'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'current-password', 'class': 'form-control'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label = 'Username:'
        self.fields['password'].label = 'Password:'

        # Add CSS class to label widgets
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'custom-label'})
        self.fields['password'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'custom-label'})
```

css code:

```
.custom-label {
    font-size: 20px;
    /* Additional styling attributes if desired */
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not changing the size of the labels. It is again changing the size of the input that we're going to give

Comment: Edit: By labels, I mean to say USERNAME, PASSWORDS

Comment: No, still I am facing the same problem...All the attributes are making changes in the input that we give